# How to interpret the radiant intensity equation?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

I would like to understand, what radiant intensity means. The [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiant_intensity) is:

$$ I_{\mathrm{e},\Omega} = \frac{\partial \phi_\mathrm{e}}{\partial \Omega} $$

Where $ \phi_\mathrm{e} $ is the radiant flux emitted, reflected, transmitted or received, and $ \Omega $ is the solid angle.

The partial derivative confuses me a bit. Does this mean, that the *radiant intensity* is a function, which represents the rate of change in the radiant flux, based on the solid angle? But as it is in the introduction, it should mean "radiant flux per unit solid angle", and not the "rate of change".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's some pretty sloppy language; it makes sense if you know what it means but it doesn't really work as a partial derivative at all.

Radiant intensity is what's defined in the first paragraph of the Wikipedia page:

> the radiant flux emitted, reflected, transmitted or received, per unit solid angle.

This quantity is a property of a radiation field at a given point, or of a localized source when examined in the far field:

- at the given point, you have power being transmitted in all sorts of directions, and
- for the localized source, the far-field radiation pattern will be stronger in some directions and weaker in some directions.

Either way, you will have a distribution of power $I_{\mathrm{e},\Omega}(\hat{\mathbf u})$ over the different directions corresponding to unit vectors $\hat{\mathbf u},$ which you can then use to calculate the radiant flux (i.e. power) that flows over some given patch $S$ of the unit sphere via the solid-angle integral
$$
\Phi_\mathrm{e}(S)
=
\int_S
I_{\mathrm{e},\Omega}(\hat{\mathbf u})
\:\mathrm d\Omega
\tag{$*$}
$$
where $\mathrm d\Omega$ is the differential of solid angle for the unit vector $\hat{\mathbf u}$. (Thus, in explicit spherical coordinates, $\mathrm d\omega=\sin(\theta)\:\mathrm d\theta\:\mathrm d\phi$ and $\hat{\mathbf u}=(\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\theta))$.)

The distribution in $(*)$ is the real definition of radiant intensity. However, defining quantities via their role inside integrals for other stuff makes some people uncomfortable, so sometimes people "differentiate" this surface integral with respect to its surface area element to say
$$
{\LARGE\text{“ }}
I_{\mathrm{e},\Omega}(\hat{\mathbf u})
=\frac{\partial \Phi_\mathrm{e}}{\partial \Omega}
{\LARGE\text{ "}}
\tag{misleading!}
$$
and similar expressions. Once you know what's going on, it's a useful shorthand, but it's not an actual derivative by any reasonable interpretation, short of a [Radon-Nikodym measure-theoretic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon.E2.80.93Nikodym_derivative) of $I_{\mathrm{e},\Omega}(\hat{\mathbf u})\:\mathrm d\Omega$ seen as a measure on the unit sphere that's absolutely continuous with respect to the solid angle (which does work, but which is hardly what's actually implied in the sources that use the notation, and which is vastly overpowered mathematics for the intended application in any case).